# jQuery, stop previous on change, input events from executing after timeout if invalid

Tags: jquery

I have 2 input text fields and 1 select field. Email, URL + city dropdown. When they all have a value and the email and URL fields are validated correct, only then i want to sent an AJAX save request.

When i invalidate the email and url fields, wait a bit, make then validate again, the console log text is fired multiple times: "3x Email, URL and select are not empty and valid"

See:

[image]

The event even fires when: both fields are invalid > both valid > within 10 sec invalidate 1 field > save event still triggered.

I only want to send the save request once and only when all fields are still valid after 10 sec. What am i missing?

```
$(document).on("change input paste", ".compEmail, .compUrl, select", function() {

    var compEmail = $('.compEmail').val().trim();
    var compUrl   = $('.compUrl').val().trim();
    var compCity  = $('.compCity').val().trim();
    var emailValid = isEmail ( compEmail );
    var urlValid   = isUrlValid ( compUrl );

    var typingTimer;
    var doneTypingInterval = 10000;

    clearTimeout( typingTimer );

    typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){

        if (
            compEmail  !== '' &&
            compUrl    !== '' &&
            compCity   !== '' &&
            emailValid === true &&
            urlValid   === true
        ) {
            console.log( 'Email, URL and select are not empty and valid' );
        }

    }, doneTypingInterval);

});
```

Comment: You are making a new timeout for every change/input/paste event.  `typingTimer`is scoped too low

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made example for you

```js
var typingTimer = null;
var doneTypingInterval = 10000;

function isEmail() {return true};
function isUrlValid() {return true};

$(document).on("change", ".compEmail, .compUrl, select", function() {
    if(typingTimer !== null) {
      clearTimeout( typingTimer );
    }

    typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        var compEmail = $('.compEmail').val().trim();
        var compUrl   = $('.compUrl').val().trim();
        var compCity  = $('.compCity').val().trim();
        var emailValid = isEmail ( compEmail );
        var urlValid   = isUrlValid ( compUrl );
        if (
            compEmail  !== '' &&
            compUrl    !== '' &&
            compCity   !== '' &&
            emailValid === true &&
            urlValid   === true
        ) {
            console.log( 'Email, URL and select are not empty and valid' );
        }

    }, doneTypingInterval);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="compEmail">
<input type="text" class="compUrl">
<select class="compCity">
<option value="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
<option value="Paris">Paris</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow! That did it! Thank you so much!! I guess moving 'var typingTimer = null;' out of the on change condition was the key.